# Blank cells appear and dissapear randomly in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode7

I'm trying to simulate a Chat Messages, and after insert some new cells, some of the oldest dissapear. And when I scroll appears again and disappear. I've tried all solutions that I found from here on SO but nothing works and I have not much idea frorm where error can come.

I'm not sure what code should I post to you tried to help, I will post my TableView code so maybe I'm doing something wrong or if you need anything else, just let me know.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.messagesCell.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return self.messagesCell[indexPath.row]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    if message.messageType == 2 {
        output.setImageUrl(message.text)
        router.navigateToGroupChatMessagesScene()
    }
    else {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

This code is how I generate the cells everytime a new message is inserted:

```
func getMessageCell(withDisplayedMessage displayedMessage: GroupChatMessages.GetChatMessages.displayedChatMessage) -> GroupChatCell {

    switch displayedMessage.messageType {
    case 0:
        if displayedMessage.sender == self.currentUser.userID {
            let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("senderCell") as! GroupChatCell

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                cell.configureCellText(withText: displayedMessage.text, andUtcSendTime: displayedMessage.utcSendTime)
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            }
            return cell
        }

        let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("receiverCell") as! GroupChatCell
        cell.configureCellAttributted(withText: displayedMessage.text, andSenderName: displayedMessage.senderName, andUtcSendTime: displayedMessage.utcSendTime)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell

    case 1:
        let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("announcementCell") as! GroupChatCell

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.configureInformationCell(withText: displayedMessage.text)
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        }

        return cell
    case 2:
        if displayedMessage.sender == self.currentUser.userID {
            let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("senderImageCell") as! GroupChatCell

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                cell.configureSenderImageCell(withImageUrl: displayedMessage.text, andUtcSendTime: displayedMessage.utcSendTime)
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            }

            return cell
        }

        let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("receiverImageCell") as! GroupChatCell

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.configureImageCell(withImageUrl: displayedMessage.text, andSenderName: displayedMessage.senderName, andUtcSendTime: displayedMessage.utcSendTime)
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        }
        return cell

    case 10: //SpecialCaseForSendingImages
        let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("senderImageCell") as! GroupChatCell

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            cell.configureSenderImageCell(withImageUrl: displayedMessage.text, andUtcSendTime: displayedMessage.utcSendTime)
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        }

        return cell
    default:
        return GroupChatCell()
    }
```

Hope you can help, and any further information I will provide you as fast I can! Thank you so much.

EDIT:

Where I receive a new message I add a new row with message information in this function:

```
    func displayMessages(viewModel: GroupChatMessages.GetChatMessages.ViewModel) {
    let displayedMessage = viewModel.displayedMessages

    print ("i'm here!")
    if let messages = displayedMessage {

        self.messages = messages
        self.messagesCell = []
        for index in 0..<messages.count {
            let cell = self.getMessageCell(withDisplayedMessage: messages[index])
            self.messagesCell.append(cell)

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
            self.messagesTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }

        print ("i'm here2!")

        firstTime = false
//            self.scrollToLastMessage(false)
        self.setVisible(hiddenTableView: false, hiddenChatLoader: true)
        self.messagesLoaded = true
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using `getMessageCell `? Where are you calling it

Comment: Don't think you should save your cell into array, save only the message object on the array and add deciding cell code into your `cellForRow`, use multiple custom cell if they look much different

Comment: I answered to Jon Rose below why I've use an array with cells, but I will try to put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get rid of the `dispatch_async` you should already be on the main
   thread.
2. Keep an array of Model objects NOT an an array of cells (in
   your case it looks like it should be an array of
   `displayedMessage`).
3. Also remember that these cells can be reused,
   so any property that you set must always be updated.  In other words
   every `if` must have an `else` when configuring a cell.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Jon thanks for the answer, I will remove it (dispatch_async) but I had the issue that when I scroll it takes too much time because I have more than 200 messages in tableview, so it takes too many time. So this is why I've tried to do an array of Cells to avoid take to do the getMessageCell every time I scroll which seems is a lot of work. I use returns inside the if and out of it, so it's like i'm using els statement.  But i'm having the issue, just when adding seems, the rest of elements went "crazy" appearing and disappearing.

Comment: The UITableview has a pool of tableviewCell that it reuses, when one leave the frame it gets put into a pool to be reused when another cell comes into frame.  This is very fast and efficient.  200 messages is not a lot for a tableview to deal with.  If your `getMessageCell` method is doing much more than just setting a few labels and images then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Seems that avoiding the array of Cells it works, but now I have the scroll problem that takes too much time,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422841/scroll-to-last-element-of-tableview-take-too-much-time