# UICollectionView/UITableView starting position (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, position, chat

What is the proper way of setting the start position?

Like all chat applications they start at the bottom, but doing it myself it populates from the top and down, and the scrollToRowAtIndexPath or setting the contentOffset is just scrolling to the bottom, which I don't prefer as the chat grows..

Comment: Check out this answer here to see if it helps: [Make Table View start from bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821783/5912335)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try reversing your UITableView ?

If chatTableView is the outlet for your UITableView, then you can do it as:

```
chatTableView = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
```

Downside with this approach is HeaderView and FooterView gets interchanged and the scroll indicator breaks!

Comment: Thanks, altough i was looking for less of a hack solution